# Error counting Child records

Tags: apex, soql, relationships

I have a parent object **Feedback** that has multiple **Feedback_Comments** as child(lookup). I have counted total Feedbacks grouping by name. But I'm unable to count the childs grouping by name. Here's what I tried...

```
public with sharing class countAll {

public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }

public countAll () {
    AggregateResult[] results = [
        SELECT Name, Count(id) Quantity,(SELECT Count(Id) FROM Feedback_Comments__r) FROM Feedback__c GROUP BY Name
    ];
    Summaries = new List<Summary>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
        Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
    }
}

// wrapper class to hold aggregate data
public class Summary {
    public Integer Quantity { get; private set; }
    public String Name { get; private set; }

    public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
        Quantity = (Integer) ar.get('Quantity');
        Name = (String) ar.get('Name');
    }
 }

}
```

I get this **ERROR**

```
Error: Compile Error: only root queries support aggregate expressions at line 6 column 37
```

Please suggest me a way. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
Select Feedback__r.Name, Count(Id)
From Feedback_Comment__c 
Group By Feedback__r.Name
```

Alternatively, if the Feedback__c and the Feedback_Comment__c records have a master-detail relationship, you could create a Roll Up Summary Field in the Feedback__c object of type COUNT that will count all of the children for a particular Feedback.

You could then use that in a query on the Feedback__c record e.g.

```
Select Name, Num_Children_Roll_Up__c 
From Feedback__c
```

This will get you the same data. It's a little difficult to know exactly what you want from your post. I'm assuming that you don't actually need to count the parent records as you have tried to do in your original query because it seems that you are grouping by name which I'm also assuming will be fairly unique values. So I think you only did that as a way to group the child records.

Comment: Is this correct syntax for child=Feedback_Comment and parent=Feedback ?

Comment: This will count all of the Feedback_Comment__c records and then group those counts by the name of the parent Feedback__c record. So if 5 of the Feedback_Comment__c records have a parent Feedback__c record with the Name of 'Foo', and 8 of the Feedback_Comment__c records have a parent with the name of 'Bar', you will get 2 AggregateResult lines returned. One with a count of 5 and the other with a count of 8.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use aggregate expressions in sub query.

You can split your query in tow queries and then merge the result.

```
AggregateResult[] results = [SELECT Name, Count(id) Quantity FROM Feedback__c GROUP BY Name];
AggregateResult[] res = [SELECT Feedback__c, count(id) qty FROM Feedback_Comments__r GROUP BY Feedback__c];
```

And then merge the result

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
SELECT Feedback.Name, Count(Id)
FROM Feedback_Comments__c
GROUP BY Feedback.Name
```

Comment: If I try SELECT Feedback__c.Name, Count(Id) FROM Feedback_Comments__c GROUP BY Feedback.Name   I get Error: Compile Error: sObject type 'Feedback_Comments__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name.

Comment: Try "SELECT Feedback.Name, Count(Id) FROM Feedback_Comment__c GROUP BY Feedback.Name" - removed potential typo with extra s.